# Initialize component from a html content received dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using VueJS with gulp and browserify in a Laravel application.

My vue components are working fine with normal html or blade files.

The problem only occurs when i try to load the html after the page is loaded. (after the vue script is loaded...)

Ex: Lets assume that the signature of the component is `<todo-list />`. I'm trying to load it within a modal. The html containing the signature is loaded dinamically from an jQuery Ajax call. `$.ajax()`.

Somethings i know about:

1. The cause of the problem is simple: Since the page was already loaded, the vue script attached to body is loaded too, so it can't recognize my component signature loaded from the dinamic html content.
2. I can use the "onShow" modal event. The problem is that i don't know **how to** call VueJS to check all the html again parsing those component tags.

Comment: You can't really dynamically load vue components after compile. You should instead v-if or v-show them and bind them to a data object. You can use watch or a computed property for async data that may not be loaded by the time the page is compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to solve this problem with v-if or v-show directives.

To solve, i needed to "compile" the Vue App again, calling:

```
var node = $('#ROOT_NODE_OF_COMPONENT').get(0);
this.$compile(node);
```

Run this code after the remote HTML content has been loaded into the DOM.

PS: VueJS v1.0